# sql query LIKE problems on c# using sqlite

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite provider on c#.
I'm trying to use SQL `select * from table where name like 'part_of_name%'`. But this query don't work correctly. Debug write `System.InvalidOperationException in application System.Data.SQLite.dll`.

Example:
I have table `Books(id, name)` with 3 items:

1. Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
2. Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
3. Godfather

In SQLite Manager query `select * from Books where name like 'Harry%'` shows me 1-st and 2-nd items, but in my c# application only 1-st and debug exception. When I try `... like '%'` my application shows me only 1-st item, but when I try `... like 'God%'` it shows me 3-rd item.
Help me please. Thanks!
This is the code:

```
sqliteConn.Open(); //open connection
sqliteDA.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Books where name like '" + text + "%'", sqliteConn); //create SQL-query in sqlite data adapter
dataSet.Tables["Books"].Clear(); //clear our dataset.table with old info
sqliteDA.Fill(dataSet, "Books"); //fill our dataset.table with info from sqlite data adapter
sqliteConn.Close(); //close connection
```

Comment: What do you see if you try setting, for example, string cmd = "select id from Books..."?  Does cmd exactly equal the query you're trying to generate?  Also, exactly which line generates the exception?

Comment: string cmd like `select * from Books where name='Harry Potter an the Chamber of Secrets'` works correct.
Exception was generated in line `sqliteDA.Fill(dataset, "Books");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameters and apply the `%` on the parameter value. Try something like this and let me know if it works:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Books where name like @name", sqliteConn); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", string.Concat(text, "%"));
sqliteDA.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
sqliteDA.Fill(dataTable); //just a DataTable instance
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what I should write instead `nameParametre`?

Comment: Nope, just an exception and incorrect result after query...
I start to think, that it's just a bug in dll when using LIKE

Comment: Could you post the exception, error message, inner exception?

Comment: `The first stage of processing exceptions of type "System.InvalidOperationException" Annex System.Data.SQLite.dll` - in line `sqliteDA.Fill(dataset, "Books");`

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much for help. I just use DataTable and try some changes in my code and it's work!